# Disable Bootstrap 3 responsiveness and load page to iframe

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I want to disable Boostrap 3.0 responsiveness then load a page (an invoice template) inside an iframe.

My iFrame HTML/CSS is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <iframe id="frame" src="http://my.app/template/one/pdf/html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

#frame {
  max-width: 1190px;    // A4 page dimension ratio
  min-height: 1684px;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I followed the [instructions here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive), and was able to disable the responsiveness when loading the page into Chrome in iPhone 5 mode.

If I omit the viewport statement from the page head, it loads slightly off the screen like this:

[image]

If I add a viewport statement (and make it 950 wide) it loads perfectly like this:

```
<meta content="width=950" name="viewport">
```

[image]

When I then place it inside of my iframe, it just runs up as responsive like this:

[image]

I can see in my iframe's page head that the CSS file is the non-responsive boostrap version.

My questions are:

Is the iframe CSS getting overridden by the parent page's CSS. I expect no, so why would you think the template not loading in desktop mode in the iFrame?

Why does it not fit into the viewport without the meta tag per bootstrap instructions?

What could be causing the text at the bottom of the page to not be scaling with the rest of the page?

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe>` is independent - it uses it's own html structure, thus it's own styling.

It's not possible to respond to your question without understanding the content of the 'invoice' page.